# Send data from view to controller in opencart

Tags: opencart2.x

I'm new to opencart MVC is it possible to send view data like this

```
<p><?php echo  "$i )".$showall['store_name']. '<br>'.$showall['store_address'].'<br>'. $showall['zipcode'].'<br>'.$showall['zipcode'].'<br>'.$showall['city'].'<br><a href='.$delaction.'>Delete</a>' ; ?> </p>
```

here I would like to send $delcation variable to controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with opencart, but I'm with MVC.
In some frameworks you have a routes file, in others the framework interprets your controller structure to provide routes. I'm assuming opencart works like the last.

You have a controller with an index function right? And to load that page via the url, something like: "http://localhost/index.php?route=test/abc"

You can try the following:

- Create an other function in the controller called delete
- The link in the href will be like so: index.php?route=test/abc/delete
- Then to pass the id of the object to delete you pass another variable in the query sting like so: index.php?route=test/abc/delete&id='.$idToDelete.'
- To retrieve the variable in the controller you do this: $idToDelete = $this->request->get['id'];
- Then you can remove that object in this function and redirect back to the correct page.

What to do if "index.php?route=test/abc/delete" doesn't work?
If opencart doesn't support this you can do the following:

- create different functions like get/update/delete etc. in the controller
- create a index function with a switch
- add a func variable in the query string like so: index.php?route=test/abc&func=delete
- Then just run the correct function for $this->request->get['func'];

Hope it works out for you!
(let me know what helped, so I can update the answer accordingly)

Comment: Ah, I understand, when I get to my computer I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller file use $data[] global variable to send data to view

Ex: In controller file `$data['var_name']="something";`

In view file you can use it has `<?php echo $var_name; ?>`

Comment: I know i can able to send data from controller to view, But i need to send data from view to controller

Comment: Use $_POST global variable with a html form.